# Can't connect remote-ssh VSCode - No Kerberos credentials available

Tags: visual-studio-code, ssh

I installed remote-ssh plugin in my VSCode in an Ubuntu machine and I got a problem connecting to the remote server. The password prompt didn't appear and I couldn't enter my ssh passphrase and I suspect that's why the connection failed. Any advice? Thanks

```
[21:29:18.094] Spawning local server with {"serverId":1,"ipcHandlePath":"/run/user/1000/vscode-ssh-askpass-43be30dd59b7e1cc43e3ac15496de2994552e19d.sock","sshCommand":"ssh","sshArgs":["-v","-T","-D","34635","-o","ConnectTimeout=15","pipeline-azure-2.nplan.io"],"dataFilePath":"/home/.config/Code/User/globalStorage/ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh/vscode-ssh-host-pipeline-azure-2.nplan.io-c3f126316369cd610563c75b1b1725e0679adfb3-0.65.7/data.json"}
[21:29:18.094] Local server env: {"DISPLAY":":0","ELECTRON_RUN_AS_NODE":"1","SSH_ASKPASS":"/home/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.65.7/out/local-server/askpass.sh","VSCODE_SSH_ASKPASS_NODE":"/snap/code/70/usr/share/code/code","VSCODE_SSH_ASKPASS_MAIN":"/home/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.65.7/out/askpass-main.js","VSCODE_SSH_ASKPASS_HANDLE":"/run/user/1000/vscode-ssh-askpass-4ae6bcfc1164348347c6920b3ec572ba3eba795f.sock"}
[21:29:18.105] Spawned 239369
[21:29:18.301] > local-server-1> Spawned ssh, pid=239378
[21:29:18.305] stderr> OpenSSH_8.2p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.2, OpenSSL 1.1.1f  31 Mar 2020
[21:29:23.099] stderr> debug1: Server host key: ssh-rsa SHA256:BJdFW33L3iusC5rckbrC9WmH7+dx5W1mC6VkyAsCFbs
[21:29:33.762] stderr> No Kerberos credentials available (default cache: FILE:/tmp/krb5cc_1000)
[21:29:33.762] stderr> 
[21:29:33.762] stderr> 
[21:29:35.107] Terminating local server
[21:29:35.111] Resolver error: Error: Connecting with SSH timed out
    at Function.Timeout (/home/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.65.7/out/extension.js:1:64785)
    at Timeout._onTimeout (/home/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.65.7/out/extension.js:1:264709)
    at listOnTimeout (internal/timers.js:554:17)
    at processTimers (internal/timers.js:497:7)
[21:29:35.124] ------
```

Answer (score 0):

I just deleted the .vscode-server folder on the server and voila!

Credits to: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-remote-release/issues/3856#issuecomment-710733921

Answer (score 0):

In my case I managed to fix this issue by adding in the section `Remote Platform` of the Remote SSH settings a custom option for the host I was connecting to.

For the `key` I set the server name (the machine I'm connecting to), and for the `value` I set `linux`, since the machine I'm connecting to runs linux.